# Android Communicate with wit.ai

Tags: android, android-volley, wit.ai

**I am trying to establish connection with wit**.AI using Volley . However, all i am getting is a **400 error**.

```
public void makeRequest(String url) {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOU'RE TOAST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("accessToken:", response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.d("error:", volleyError.toString());

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Authorization:", "Bearer SAMPLETOKENHERE");
            return headers;
        }

    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue . It was because I put a ":" in my authorization . I didn't know I did not needed it.  It works now